# Setting thread affinity in C# .Net Core 6 on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to set the thread affinity of a thread to specific cores on Ubuntu Linux (using WSL).
I have written a c program to verify that in principle it works.
But my C# program ends with segmentation fault when trying to set the affinity with pthread_setafinity_np.

BTW: That I have to different code for this on windows or linux ist not what I understand as platform independent :-(

Here is my C# program

````
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
  [DllImport("libc.so.6")]
  static extern int pthread_setaffinity_np(IntPtr thread, ulong cpusetsize, IntPtr cpuset);


  static void Main()
  {
    // Create a new thread
    Thread thread = new Thread(MyThreadFunction);

    // Start the thread
    thread.Start();

    // Wait for the thread to complete
    thread.Join();
  }

  static void MyThreadFunction()
  {
   
    // Get the current thread ID
    IntPtr threadId = new IntPtr(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    // Create a CPU set with CPU 0
    ulong cpuMask = 1;
    IntPtr cpuSet = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(cpuMask));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(cpuMask, cpuSet, false);

    // Set the CPU affinity of the thread
    int result = pthread_setaffinity_np(threadId, (ulong)Marshal.SizeOf(cpuMask), cpuSet);

    if (result != 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Failed to set thread affinity: {result}");
    }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cpuSet);

 
  }```
````

Comment: [An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-8.0#getting-information-about-and-controlling-threads)

Comment: I guessed that that might be the problem and tried to use pthread_self() to get the thread id, but again I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: Are they the same segment fault?

Answer (score -2):

ManagedThreadId is not the OS thread id, you should dllimport the gettid().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).